# Sequentially print data output as a formatted table in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, console, format, output

I'm looking at Python packages that provide an easy way to make formatted 'pretty' tables as text output. [This answer provides a few suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26937531/1609514). The catch is, I want to print my table sequentially (one row at a time) similar to a logger.

To illustrate, the output of [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) is perfectly fine for my application:

```
from tabulate import tabulate   
some_data = [['08:01', 1.00, 32], ['08:02', 1.01, 33], ['08:03', 1.02, 33]]
headers = ['Time', 'x', 'n']
print(tabulate(some_data, headers=headers, tablefmt='plain'))
```

Output:

```
Time       x    n
08:01   1      32
08:02   1.01   33
08:03   1.02   33
```

But I want to do each operation one at a time not all-at-once:
 1. print the headers
 2. print the first row of data
 3. print the next
 4. ...etc.

Of course, I tried this:

```
print(tabulate(some_data[0:1], tablefmt='plain'))
```

Output:

```
08:01  1  32
```

This obviously won't work perfectly because the formatting of each row will be different each time.  So I need a package where you can set up the table first (specifying the required formats, column widths, etc).  And then output data one row at a time.

Does anyone know if this is possible in one of these packages or another package that I could import?

Comment: Do you have to do it one line at a time? It's easy enough to build a single list of all results, then print that once - unless you want 'real-time' updates as the data is processed?

Comment: Yes I want real-time updates of each row.  Similar to a logger.  One every minute typically.

Answer (score 3):

You can get quite good simple tables just using the builtin python `format` command. You can specify a format string, then use that as a 'template' and pass in data to be applied to that template.

```
format_string = "{:<10}{:<8}{:<10}"
print(format_string.format(*headers))
for entry in some_data:
    print(format_string.format(*entry))
```

For a full list of the various options for padding etc, see https://pyformat.info

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I know I could write my own code to do it.  I would prefer to see if there is an existing package to do it first.  Also, the width and number of columns may change each time I run the script so that makes manually setting up the formatting tedious.

Comment: You should be able to dynamically generate the format string based on the number of columns present in your data - though width is always going to be a guess if you are iterating as you won't know the widest column until you reach it - though  header column width might be a good approximation.

Comment: Yes I know.  In fact it was half-way through writing the code to do that that I thought "hang on, there must be an existing package for this".

Answer (score 1):

### str.format()

You would be able to use string formatting using `.format`, as below:

```
some_data = [['08:01', 1.00, 32], ['08:02', 1.01, 33], ['08:03', 1.02, 33]]
h = ['Time', 'x', 'n']

print('{:<10s} {:<5s} {:<5s}'.format(*h))
for list_ in some_data:
    print('{:<10s} {:.2f} {:<5d}'.format(*list_))
```

This would then print the following:

```
Time       x     n
08:01      1.00 32
08:02      1.01 33   
08:03      1.02 33
```

You can play around with the values inside the curly braces `{}` to get a more desired output, but this essentially does the job.

More information on string formatting can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html

**Edit:** Used unpacking `*`

Comment: Obviously I could write my own code to do it but I'm looking for an existing package.